# TlSharp uses TlRequestGetParticipants to obtain the maximum number of channel members only 10K. Is there any way to break through this limit

Tags: telegram, tdlib, tlsharp

```
while (offset < (res.FullChat as TLChannelFull).ParticipantsCount)
            {
                var pReq = new TLRequestGetParticipants()
                {
                    Channel = new TLInputChannel() { AccessHash = chat.AccessHash.Value, ChannelId = chat.Id },
                    Filter = new TLChannelParticipantsRecent() { },
                    //Filter = new TLChannelParticipantsSearch() { Q = "a" },
                    Limit = 200,
                    Offset = offset,

                };
                var pRes = await client.SendRequestAsync<TLChannelParticipants>(pReq);
                //result.Users.AddRange(pRes.users.lists.Cast<TLUser>());
                offset += 200;
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
```

I can only get 10K users with this method, and I can't break this limit

Comment: Please help me,I found some data that said aggressive = true but the TlSharp global search did not see this field or method